# Transform opentelemetry spans log event

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector, otel

I've been working with OpenTelemetry Collector using opentelemetry-collector-contrib:0.85.0. I have set up the auto instrumentation and started receiving spans. but I realized in the spans log event I saw the Token printed out like this.

```
event = Token: abcdefghijklmn......
context = []
level   = info
```

is there a way to maybe hide or transform it into another string? to be something like this

```
event = Token: ********
context = []
level   = info
```